# ¿Hay forma de ver una query de vista con permisos solo de lectura?

Tags: sql-server

Necesito obtener la `query` de una vista de una base de datos `sql server` y solo tengo permisos de lectura y al tener solo permisos de lectura, el campo diseño sale desactivado.

¿Hay forma de ver la `query` sin los permisos?.

Answer (score 1):

A partir de SQL server 2005 puedes obtener la Query con la que se creo una vista.

Puedes obtenerla con esta query de SQL server >=2005:

```
SELECT definition
FROM sys.objects objs
INNER JOIN sys.sql_modules m on m.object_id = objs.object_id
WHERE objs.object_id = object_id( 'dbo.NombreVista') AND objs.type = 'V'
```

O con esta para SQL server >= 2008

```
SELECT object_definition (OBJECT_ID(N'dbo.vEmployee'))
```

Comment: Gracias por contestar tan rápido, pero he intentando las dos sentencias y devuelven null, supongo que devolverá null por tema de permisos  ya que como digo en la pregunta solo tengo permisos de lectura, he probado tu sentencia en otra base de datos que si tengo permisos y si que funciona perfecto. Supongo que no hay forma de hacerlo con permisos de solo lectura, de todas formas thaks!!! @miguel